# Sort values in dataframe, but randomize order of items with same value

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, shuffle

I am writing a recommendation system that recommends products based on a score assigned to each product, for example in the following dataframe:

```
index   product_name     score
0       prod_1           2
1       prod_2           2
2       prod_3           1
3       prod_4           3
```

I can of course sort this dataframe by score, using `sort_values('score', ascending = False)`, however, this will always result in the following dataframe:

```
index   product_name     score
3       prod_4           3
0       prod_1           2
1       prod_2           2
2       prod_3           1
```

However, I would like to randomly shuffle the order of `prod_1` and `prod_2`, as they have the same score. It doesn't seem like `sort_values` has any way of achieving this.

The only solution I can come up with is to fetch all possible scores from the dataframe, then make a new dataframe for each score, shuffle those, and then stitch them back together, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: How about shuffling first and then sorting by score with the stable algorithm?

Comment: Ah yes, that would also work quite well, not sure how I didn't think about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a new column with completely random numbers (use e.g. numpy.random.randint) and then sort it by both?

```
sort_values(by=["score","rand_col"], ascending=[False,False])
```